# TableSorter: How to Hide/Display Results in TableSorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I want to Hide Results in a table if the user dont search anything yet, and Show Filtering Results when the user write in filtering column

How can i do this? This its my code

```js
$("#tableAccionesHabilitadas").tablesorter({
            theme: "bootstrap",
            widthFixed: true,
            widgets: ["filter", "columns", "zebra", "editable"],
            widgetOptions: {
                zebra: ["even", "odd"],
                columns: ["primary", "secondary", "tertiary"],
                filter_reset: ".reset",
                filter_cssFilter: [
                    'form-control',
                    'form-control filter-selecction1',
                    'form-control filter-selecction2'
                ],
                filter_startsWith: true,
                filter_functions: {
                    1: {
                        "Habilitado": function (e, n, f, i) { return f == e; },
                        "Inhabilitado": function (e, n, f, i) { return f == e; }
                    },
                    2: {
                        "Habilitado": function (e, n, f, i) { return f == e; },
                        "Inhabilitado": function (e, n, f, i) { return f == e; }
                    }

                }

            }
        }).tablesorterPager({
            container: $(".ts-pagerAccionesHabilitadas"),
            cssGoto: ".pagenum",
            removeRows: true,
            output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})'

        });
```

Thanks